# Excel VBA code .find throwing a 91 error: object variable or With block variable not set and I don't understand why?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to grab a value from one cell, then in another worksheet find that value, if there is a match return the ID in the column to the left (this all works fine). If there isn't a match I want to create an ID and add that + the value to a table. Problem is when there isn't a match I get the error 'Object variable or With block variable not set'. I'm expecting the .find to return 'nothing' hence the If - Is Nothing statement, don't understand why I keep getting this error, please help!

```
Dim selected_item As String
Dim found_item_id As String
Dim found_item_id_cell As Range

Range("D3").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    selected_item = ActiveCell.Value
    Set found_item_id_cell = Worksheets("items").Range("B:B").Find(selected_item, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -1)
        If found_item_id_cell Is Nothing Then
            'nothing found - generate new ID and add record
            Range("G1").Value = "Item not Found"
        Else
            found_item_id = found_item_id_cell.Value
            'something is found - no action
            Range("G1").Value = found_item_id
        End If
    
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Inputting a 'selected_item' I know doesn't match and expect "item not found" to appear in cell G1, but just get the error. Works fine for values that do match. Debug shows error on the `Set found_item_id_cell = Worksheets("items").Range("B:B").Find(selected_item, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, -1)`

Comment: You are going to need to test that the `Find` returned something before trying to offset.  If the `Find` does not find a match it will return `Nothing` and you cannot offset `Nothing`

Comment: When using `Find`, *always* specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters (you're missing `LookAt`), and then always test if the find succeeded.

Comment: Testing if the find succeded means you can't chain anything after the find call, so the `.Offset(0, -1)` in `Find(...).Offset(0, -1)` is a no-go. Move the `Offset` to inside the `Else`: `found_item_id = found_item_id_cell.Offset(0, -1).Value`.

Comment: @BigBen Got it! Thank you so much, moved the '.offset(0, -1)' down to the Else block and works perfectly, much appreciated